# Check Balance Delimiters Function Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, stack

I want to write a function where you enter a list of delimiters tuples, and a string,
And the function should check if the string is balanced according to the tuples we input. And return a boolean value.

For example:

INPUT: `balanceList [('[','}')] "[}"`

OUTPUT: `True`

INPUT: `balanceList [('{',')'] "{}"`

OUTPUT: `False`

Here is my current code:

```
balanceList :: [(Char, Char)] -> String -> Bool
balanceList pairs string = balanced string emptyStack
  where
    balanced [] stack = isEmpty stack

    balanced (c:string) stack
      |c `elem1` (map fst pairs) = balanced string (push c stack)
      |c `elem1` (map snd pairs) = popTest (pop stack)
        where
          popTest Nothing = False
          popTest (Just (x,s)) = x == c && balanced string s

    balanced (_:string) stack  = balanced string stack
```

When I input `balanceList [('[','}')] "[}"` I get `False`instead of `True`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What are push and pop?

Comment: They are functions for Stacks
`push` adds an element in a stack
and `pop` removes the top element of a stack

Comment: it looks like you used a custom module, not some buitin stack, since Haskell's link is already something that can be used as a stack.

Comment: yes that's true.
I used my own module.

Answer (score 3):

With `push c stack`, you are pushing the opening parenthesis on the stack, not the closing one. You thus check if the current character is the same as the opening when you check if it is closing.

A simpler approach is to push the expected closing parenthesis on the stack, and thus in that case pop the stack, so something like:

```
balanceList :: Eq a => [(a, a)] -> [a] -> Bool
balanceList pairs = go []
    where go [] [] = True
          go (c:ss) (c':cs)
            | c == c' = go ss cs -- closing parenthesis
          go s (c:cs)
            | Just c' <- lookup c pairs = …
          go _ _ = False
```

We here thus first check if both the stack and the string are empty, and then return `True`. In case both the stack and string are not empty, we first check if the stack head `c` and the first charcter of the string match, in which case we pop the stack and recurse on the tail of the string. If that fails, we check if the first charcter `c` is an element of the `pairs`, and we get the co-parenthesis `c'` that we then need to push on the stack. I leave implementing this as an exercise.

Comment: I think your example code has different semantics if the input contains non-delimiter characters.

Comment: @Noughtmare: yes, although that is actually only adding an `otherwise` guard at the last-but one clause to recurse on the tail of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
      |c `elem1` (map fst pairs) = balanced string (push c stack)
```

What are you pushing on the stack here?

Comment: If "c" the 1st character of the String is an element of the 1st tuple, it (the "c") should be pushed to the stack.

Comment: @RLP It's better to think in higher level concepts. What is "c" here? Is it the opening delimiter? What should be pushed onto the stack? The opening delimiter?